# Is MsiViewClose call required even when MsiCloseHandle is there?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windows-installer, custom-action

I open a MSI database view using `MsiDatabaseOpenView` followed by a call to `MsiViewExecute`. Then do I need to call `MsiViewClose` even if I do make a call to `MsiCloseHandle`?  Will `MsiCloseHandle` not call `MsiViewClose` (or do something to close all required handles internally)?

The actual reason why I'm asking this:
There is a class `PMSIHANDLE` which is recommended instead of manually closing the handles (destructor will call `MsiCloseHandle` - source code visible in VS). So when I open the view using `MsiDatabaseOpenView` and wrap the handle in `PMSIHANDLE`, I am relieved from calling `MsiCloseHandle`, but I must(?) call `MsiViewClose`!?

Comment: To speed things up I like to pillage github for stuff like this (old code that can be tweaked). Saves time I think. [Here is a query](https://github.com/search?q=MsiDatabaseOpenView+MsiViewExecute+MsiCloseHandle+PMSIHANDLE&type=Code). First hit (Apress/def-guid-to-win-installer) is from Phil Wilson. MSI MVP back in the day and author of [The Definitive Guide to Windows Installer](https://github.com/search?q=MsiDatabaseOpenView+MsiViewExecute+MsiCloseHandle+PMSIHANDLE&type=Code). [Reliable information (download link)](https://github.com/Apress/def-guide-to-win-installer).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Even Phil is not perfect. Actually I think [this code](https://github.com/Apress/def-guide-to-win-installer/blob/024a4a8657ab8135db9974a9b9b99a79b35b9da0/Chapter14/MsiStream/MsiStream.cpp) even leaks a handle, because he is missing a `MsiCloseHandle(hView)` at the end of the code. He is doing it right the first time at [line 53](https://github.com/Apress/def-guide-to-win-installer/blob/024a4a8657ab8135db9974a9b9b99a79b35b9da0/Chapter14/MsiStream/MsiStream.cpp#L53) though, so this seems to be a simple oversight. The `MsiViewClose()` calls are obsolete there, but they do no harm.

Comment: I am not a C++ expert. Not sure Phil himself has control over that repository, or else you could submit a change for him to review? Community input is how open source gets better I suppose. I use tools to help me with C++. I think there are too many things to mess up - too much to remember. Are there any online analyzers for C++ code (that are any good), like there is for [html](https://validator.w3.org/)? (not important, just came to mind).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

`MsiViewClose()` is not required to close the handle. It is only required, if you want to run `MsiViewExecute()` on the same view again, which can be useful to pass different parameters to a parameterized SQL query. This is stated in the remarks of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/msiquery/nf-msiquery-msiviewclose):

> The MsiViewClose function must be called before the MsiViewExecute
>   function is called again on the view, unless all rows of the result
>   set have been obtained with the MsiViewFetch function.

In the most common use case, where you only do a single `MsiViewExecute()` call for a given view, you don't need to call `MsiViewClose()`:

```
PMSIHANDLE pView;
UINT res = MsiDatabaseOpenViewW( hDatabase, L"SELECT * FROM `File`", &pView );
if( res == ERROR_SUCCESS )
{
    res = MsiViewExecute( pView, nullptr );
}
// Destructor of PMSIHANDLE calls MsiCloseHandle()
```

### Side Notes

From a modern C++ point of view, `PMSIHANDLE` appears to be badly designed. For one, it provides no protection against accidentally copying of a handle, which would result in calling `MsiViewClose()` twice on the same handle. Also while the implicit conversion to `MSIHANDLE*` can be convenient, it is also dangerous because it makes it possible to accidentally overwrite an existing handle, without closing it first.

Here is an alternative to `PMSIHANDLE` based on C++11s [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
// A deleter for MSIHANDLE.
struct MsiHandleDeleter
{
    // This alias enables us to actually store values of type MSIHANDLE in the unique_ptr
    // (by default it would be MSIHANDLE*).
    using pointer = MSIHANDLE;

    void operator()( MSIHANDLE h ) const { if( h ) ::MsiCloseHandle( h ); }
};

// A RAII wrapper for MSI handle. The destructor automatically closes the handle, if not 0.
using UniqueMsiHandle = std::unique_ptr< MSIHANDLE, MsiHandleDeleter >;
```

**Usage example:**

```
UniqueMsiHandle record{ ::MsiCreateRecord( 1 ) };
::MsiRecordSetInteger( record.get(), 1, 42 );
// Destructor takes care of calling MsiCloseHandle(), just like PMSIHANDLE.
```

Compared to `PMSIHANDLE` it's more cumbersome to use it with functions that have `MSIHANDLE*` out parameters, but this can easily be remedied by creating wrapper functions or classes that work with `UnqiueMsiHandle`.

**Advantages:**

- Less ways to do things wrong.
- Clear ownership and [moveability](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move).
- Everyone who is used to `std::unique_ptr` will immediately understand the semantics of `UniqueMsiHandle`.

Comment: Yeah, `PMSIHANDLE` was designed back in 1995. C++ wasn't modern yet. :)

Comment: "*You were there... In the fires of mount Doom... Thousands of days ago...*" :-).

Comment: @Rob I feel a bit ashamed for criticising without providing an alternative. Fixed. :)